# Is it possible to transfer money from paypal to any master card?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, mastercard

One of my client offers me to pay through paypal , but paypal is not supported in our country . I have a master card which is provided by payoneer . Is it possible to transfer fund from paypal to my mastercard ?

Comment: You can if Payoneer gives you their bank account in which you link to your PayPal account. Or apply for a PayPal MasterCard which is linked to your funds in PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

No.

PayPal payments are credited to a PayPal account. PayPal doesn't let you pay arbitrary banks or credit cards, that defeats the purpose of PayPal and there are other services which can do that cheaper or with less hassle.

You need to find another mutually available and satisfactory option with your client.

Comment: There are a few exceptions then. I connected my bank with my paypal account, allowing me to transfer money between them quite easilly. If I pay with paypal, paypal takes it from my bank. If I ask for a refund, I can in turn put it back on my bank. Not sure if this would even work on creditcards though.

Comment: @Migz reread the question. PayPal doesn't operate in the OP's country. They are asking if someone with a PayPal account can use it to directly send money to someone else's credit card. What you are describing is a different scenario. After all, if it's your Mastercard and your PayPal account, you could just withdraw the money to your bank then pay your card as normal.